# Production.rb not reading environment variables in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, production-environment

I'm using this action mailer setup for a production application

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'example.com',
    user_name:            ENV['EMAIL'],
    password:             ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD'],
    authentication:       'login',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

On my DigitalOcean droplet (Ubuntu 14.04) I ran

```
export EMAIL="email"
export EMAIL_PASSWORD="password"
```

However, It's not working. I also tried adding them to my `.bashrc` file and that didn't work either.

I know that other posts might suggest using something like the figaro gem or dotenv, however, I wouldn't really know how to use those gems in my situation. This application is for a client who wants to use `smtp` for sending emails. I wouldn't be able to get their credentials and store them on my local machine. Luckily, It's very easy to access the server on DigitalOcean because it has a built-in ssh feature on the website that allows you to access the droplets.

This means that they would have to manually enter in the lines `export EMAIL="theiremailgoeshere"` and the same for the password. But as stated, this isn't working for some reason

Any help is appreaciated, thank you so much!

I don't know if this will help but I'm using a Digital Ocean droplet to host my website. I have an Ubuntu (14.04) image running on it and I'm using Nginx and Passenger.

Comment: What kind of web server and app server are you using for production environment?

Comment: Did you [allow less secure apps access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)?

Comment: Try using `ENV.fetch('EMAIL')` instead. It probably won't solve the problem but it will raise an error if the ENV var is not set which makes debugging much easier.

Comment: @max Yes, I did get an error when I used `ENV.fetch('EMAIL')`. How should I go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

Env vars from `~/.bashrc` are only set for programs that are opened using the bash shell. Also there is a problem if you are ssh'ing into the system as one user and your the web server is running as a separate lesser privileged user.

You can set [system wide env vars in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Setting_values_to_environment_variables) in `/etc/environment` and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`. These ENV vars will be set for all users and all shells opened - and even programs opened from the GUI.

However I would recommend you use a more specific key to like `MYAPP_EMAIL` avoid potential conflicts.

Comment: You gave me two paths. Do I have to add the environment variables to both files? or can I just pick one? I also don't know what the `*.sh` file is

Comment: Pick one. By `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` I mean that you create a shell script (.sh) file in `/etc/profile.d/`. That lets you use separate files instead of tossing everything into one file. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Setting_values_to_environment_variables